# 1996 Chevy camaro 3.8l

Tags: shifting, camaro

I was driving my camaro down the street the other day going about 50 mph and I heard and felt a thud and the next thing that happens my car starts to slow down only going about 15 - 20mph with the rpms shooting up and not going back down... does anyone have and idea what the issue can be? I should mention I checked the tranny fluid the day before and it was full before and after the issue? And another thing is the speedometer  is stuck at 50!

Comment: I'm not following your question at all.  In one place you say "rpms shooting up and not going back down" but then you say "the rpm is stuck at 50".  These are contradictory statements.  Please consider reworking your question to more clearly state the symptoms.

Comment: Speedometer is stuck at 50 my bad..

Comment: From the little information in your text it sounds like it's the gearbox that has locked into, or limited to a lower gear. I'm not sure about the Camaro, but it's very common that the speedometer goes to the gearbox, so if the gearbox is locked and the speedo stuck, much points at the gearbox. However what's wrong with it is very hard to say.

Comment: If you start the engine now, do the revs shoot back up?

Comment: Up date I got to my camaro due to it being in another town and I started it up and now everything is normal? What should I do?